# Querulous -- Is it usable with a database other than MySQL?

Tags: database, scala, querulous

I'm studying querulous and started with this code:

```
import com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.QueryEvaluator
class Querulous {

  def test {
    val queryEvaluator = QueryEvaluator("org.h2.Driver", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test", "sa", "")
    val names = queryEvaluator.select("select (name) from mytable where id in (?)", List(1, 2, 3)) {
      row =>
        row.getString("name")
    }
    println(names)
  }
}
```

The result of execution is following:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:343)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2308)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
>           at com.**mysql**.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.ApachePoolingDatabase.open(ApachePoolingDatabase.scala:93)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.Database$class.withConnection(Database.scala:33)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.ApachePoolingDatabase.withConnection(ApachePoolingDatabase.scala:45)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.withTransaction(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:66)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.select(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:23)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.QueryEvaluator$class.select(QueryEvaluator.scala:88)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.select(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:19)
>           at org.database.Querulous.test(Querulous.scala:10)
>           at org.database.Main$.main(Main.scala:4)
>           at org.database.Main.main(Main.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:60)
>           at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:47)
>           at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Run.scala:50)
>           at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Run.scala:50)
>           at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
>           at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
>   Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   org.h2.Driver
>           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1201)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1154)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:275)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:292)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2308)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.ApachePoolingDatabase.open(ApachePoolingDatabase.scala:93)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.Database$class.withConnection(Database.scala:33)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.database.ApachePoolingDatabase.withConnection(ApachePoolingDatabase.scala:45)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.withTransaction(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:66)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.select(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:23)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.QueryEvaluator$class.select(QueryEvaluator.scala:88)
>           at com.twitter.querulous.evaluator.StandardQueryEvaluator.select(StandardQueryEvaluator.scala:19)
>           at org.database.Querulous.test(Querulous.scala:10)
>           at org.database.Main$.main(Main.scala:4)
>           at org.database.Main.main(Main.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:60)
>           at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:47)
>           at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Run.scala:50)
>           at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Run.scala:50)
>           at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
>           at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
>   [info] == run == [error] Error running
>   run: Nonzero exit code: 1

As for me, it doesn't look very nice. It seems that querulous can be used only with mysql rdbms. Is that true?
Secondly, there are a bunch of querulous projects[1](https://github.com/twitter/querulous) [2](https://github.com/bwmcadams/querulous-generic) [3](https://github.com/rhyskeepence/querulous) [4](https://github.com/nkallen/querulous) with slightly different instructions, for examle, from [1](https://github.com/twitter/querulous):

> val queryEvaluator =
>   QueryEvaluator("host", "username",
>   "password")

(I didn't figure out what "host" means)

from [2](https://github.com/bwmcadams/querulous-generic):

> val queryEvaluator =
>   QueryEvaluator("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
>   "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb",
>   "username", "password")

(used this as sample)

And at last, I used "com.twitter" % "querulous_2.8.0" % "1.5.0" for binaries and cloned git://github.com/twitter/querulous.git to have sources (no 1.5 sources available for download) but they doesn't have **any** comments.

So, questions: can querulous be used with databases other than mysql?
If so, please specify example how connect to it; scaladoc location; normal (with comments) sources location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fork claims to be more of a vanilla version of Querulous:

https://github.com/ollekullberg/querulous-light

From their readme:

> Note about this Fork
>
> This is a fork of Querulous-generic (Querulous-generic is in turn a fork of the Twitter     version). This fork will:
>
> - Work on Scala 2.8
> - Work on all RDBMs (Well, I've only tried H2, so I do not really know)
> - Not have any dependencies to Twitters StandardProject module.
>
> The more advanced features (timeout and so on) probably don't work, since I had to smash some code to get here.

While I use querulous, I've only used it with mysql and have not tried this fork myself.

Comment: ok, I see that it isn't usable now. Maybe I will try querulous after 6 months.